# Session in webpy+apache doesn't work

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, web.py

According to this [example](http://webpy.org/cookbook/mod_wsgi-apache) I tried to
create little webapp which uses session. This works but I have problem with session I think 
it doesn't work because in my browser I always see 1 when get /count page, although it should
incremented each time when I request the page.
Also, I tried to use DBStore instead of DiskStore but got the same result.

Do you have any guesses why sessions doesn't work?
Maybe I always get new session when request /count page??

I use ubuntu 12.04, webpy 0.36, mod_wsgi 4.2
Here is the code, apache config and error.log:

```
import web
import os

urls = (
'/count', 'count',
'/reset', 'reset'
)

web.config.debug = False
app = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=False)
curdir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
session = web.session.Session(app, 
web.session.DiskStore(os.path.join(curdir,'sessions')),initializer = {'count': 0})

application = app.wsgifunc()

class count:
    def GET(self):
        session.count += 1
        return str(session.count)

class reset:
    def GET(self):
        session.kill()
        return ""
```

----apache config------

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/webpy-app/documents
    AddType text/html .py

    <Directory /var/www/webpy-app/documents>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/webpy-app/code.py/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Also, I noticed that session files in /session aren't created while I request /count page, although they should be.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add the cookie path as well before the session code.

Like this:

`web.config.session_parameters['cookie_path'] = '/`'

and then:

```
session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore(os.path.join(curdir,'sessions')),initializer = {'count': 0})
```

Not sure why this is not in the documentation but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it doesnt help!

Comment: Ok. Then not sure what the problem might be. If you like you can check out this quick login example using web.py and sessions: https://bitbucket.org/victorkohler/webpy-login/src

Answer (score 0):

Your Apache/mod_wsgi configuration means your web application will be multiprocess and so requests likely going to different process each time. Use mod_wsgi daemon mode instead and ensure you only have one process (the default for daemon mode).

The Apache/mod_wsgi process will also run as special user and likely don't have write access to the directory you specified for session files.